# android - spacing between groups ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView and I want to have less space between the group rows. dividerHeight is already set to zero, I don't get where those top/bottom margins come from. See a screenshot below (please ignore the volume control which accidentally came up)

[image]

I need to reduce that spacing between rows but can't manage it.

ListView:

```
 <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

in the Activity:

```
            getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
    getExpandableListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

Grouprow XML:

```
    <CheckedTextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="65dp"


android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/hello_world"

android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="65sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**UPDATE**

The grouprow now looks like that:

```
 <CheckedTextView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:paddingLeft="20dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="65sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I enabled the listSelector and figured out that the row height is still larger than the height of the actual text.. looking for a solution

Comment: nope, this is a CheckedTextView, I posted the code above

Answer (score 0):

You are giving fixed height to your row data, so it cause a problem.

Use

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Instead

> android:layout_height="65dp"

Second solution@

Remove `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

and check and let me know, else will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative values in your margin attributes to reduce spacing.  Try this in your CheckedTextView:

android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for programmatically

`expListView.setDividerHeight(0);`

(or) mension in expandable listview divider height value as 0 (xml)

`android:dividerHeight="0dp"`